# Is it possible to send messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to offline users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, offline

I'm working on a Progressive Web App (PWA) and I need to send important reminders through push messages. Users should receive them even if they are offline.
Is it possible to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM) for that (maybe preload the messages or something like that?) or do I need to get a different route for offline?

Comment: What do you mean by the user being offline? If they have no network/cell signal on their device, it'll be impossible to deliver any messages to them. So while you can *send* them (e.g. from Cloud Functions as Renaud answered), the user won't receive the messages until they're back online.

Answer (score 4):

*Adapted after AL's comments below and Frank's comment above*

It is possible to send "push messages" via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to a device that is offline, **BUT** the user will only see the message **when the device is online again**. If the device is offline it cannot receive immediately any (push) message from the "external world". If you want to trigger some reminders that are immediately visible for a device which is offline, you will have to do it **locally**, on the device, and not by relying on a push from the "external world".

So, having said that, if you want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages, you can do it by using Cloud Functions, i.e. from a "trusted environment". Have a look at this official Firebase Cloud Function sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

You could trigger this Cloud Function when e.g. a new item is saved in the database (Real Time Database or Firestore), or an existing one is modified/deleted, or a file is uploaded to Storage, etc.

Comment: FCM requires a reliable network connection on the client's side in order to for it to receive the message.

Comment: @AL have a look at Frank’s comment above. Without some connectivity a smartphone will not be able to receive a notification or message.

Comment: Exactly. Hence the upvote I gave it. The question was "*Can I use FCM offline?*" which is pointing to the client app and your answer is saying "*yes*". Did you just misinterpret your answer or did I miss something?

Comment: @AL I don't know if it is a misinterpretation but, while writing this answer, I made the assumption that the OP was aware that the messages could only reach the device where the connectivity is back. As a matter of fact, the OP mentions "**push messages**", so I don't think he/she means these messages shall be generated automatically, locally, by the application. However I agree that this assumption is not clearly stated in my answer. To be complete, when I saw Frank's comment I thought I had nothing to add. Note that I am not arguing or "negotiating", I have no problem with the downvote :-)

Comment: Hey Renaud. No negotiations or any arguments intended as well. I'd be willing to remove the downvote, I was just looking for clarity. The way I read your answer was "*what if I am a new user*" and "*Yes*" starting the answer might confuse them. If you could specify that the OP (dev side) could actually interact with FCM server even when the device is offline, then it should be fine. Cheers! :)

Comment: @AL. Thanks for your constructive comments! I've updated the answer. Hoping it is more clear for possible future readers.

Comment: What about not having the database? Currently I am getting familiar with the FCM but I do not have any database. From my backend API when app triggers given actions, I want to push notifications to other users via FCM - not push notification to be exact but that second type called "Data Messages". So how about that offline case in such scenario?